# Save image in specific resolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying for hours to simply output a certain plot in a specific resolution (320x240).

```
  xmax = 320; ymax = 240;
  xmin = 0; ymin = 0;
  figure;
  set(gcf,'position',[1060 860 320 240]);
  axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);
  plot(someLinesAndPointsInTheRange320X240);
  saveas(gca,outName,'jpg');
  export_fig(outName);
```

Where `saveas` output the jpg image in an arbitrary resolution. `export_fig` is still showing the axes.

Adding an `axis off` or `axis tight` doesn't help either.
Has anyone an idea?

UPDATE:
The problem is solved. Just for completeness here is my current solution:

```
  xmax = 320; ymax = 240;
  xmin = 0; ymin = 0;
  figure;
  set(gcf,'position',[1060 860 320 240]);
  subaxis(1,1,1, 'Spacing', 0.01, 'Padding', 0, 'Margin', 0);  % Removes padding
  axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);
  plot(someLinesAndPointsInTheRange320X240);
  axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);

  set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]); % Removes axis notation
  I = frame2im(getframe(gcf)); %Convert plot to image (true color RGB matrix).
  J = imresize(I, [240, 320], 'bicubic'); %Resize image to resolution 320x240
  imwrite(J, 'outName.jpg'); %Save image to file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is converting figure to image, and use `imresize`.

Fixing the figure position to match 320x240 resolution is possible, but using `imresize` is simpler (I think).

The following code sample, convert figure to image, and use `imrezie` to set resolution to 320x240:

```
figure;
% xmax = 320; ymax = 240;
% xmin = 0; ymin = 0;  
% set(gcf,'position',[1060 860 320 240]);
% axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);

plot(sin(-pi:0.01:pi)); %Example figure
I = frame2im(getframe(gcf)); %Convert plot to image (true color RGB matrix).
J = imresize(I, [240, 320], 'bicubic'); %Resize image to resolution 320x240
imwrite(J, 'J.jpg'); %Save image to file
```

Comment: This actually helped me to solve it, thanks a lot. For completeness I will post the full solution (without axis and padding) under my question

Comment: @mcExchange The removal of the padding and minimizing the spacing is key.  Thanks for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier solution for this.

Saying you have your figure, gcf, you capture the frame and just use imresize to edit the object property cdata of your frame.

```
frame = getframe(gcf);
frame.cdata = imresize(frame.cdata,[240, 320]);
```

Then you can write your video using this frame, which now has the assigned resolution.

```
writeVideo(VideoObj,frame);
```

It works quite well.