# Exporting Figures in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to export figurtes in specific height and width in Matlab. Right now I change the Height and width of the figure.

```
set(gcf,'position',[100 10 320 230])
```

And then export it with `export_fig`. But I fell this is pretty small, as legend appears over my signal.

Is there any way to plot it properly and then export it in the height and width we need? or we have to set the figure in that size and then we need to export it?

Comment: `export_fig` has an horrifying amount of optionals parameters that you can tune to perfectly choose almost everything. Are you using them?

Comment: I think you can use the following solution I posted: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375620/save-image-in-specific-resolution-in-matlab/39375867#39375867](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375620/save-image-in-specific-resolution-in-matlab/39375867#39375867).

Comment: @AnderBiguri, are you talking about: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig I cannot find how to tune the fig while using `export_fig`

Comment: Then you are not looking hard enough. There are tons of examples and usage cases.

Comment: @Rotem I just checked `imwrite` . it does not have an option for pdf. Unfortunately i am exporting as pdf.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , Can you point me  some examples which might be relevant to my case?

Comment: No, I am not an expert on that. You shoudl look a bit more and try a couple of cases.